# UI appearance different running through visual studio vs installed application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a program in C# using WPF for the GUI.  I've always had trouble with it not coming out exactly the way I design it, but I've never noticed this happening before:  The margins of the window are different between installing the program and running it vs just running it through visual studio.  The left window is a screen shot of running the installed program, and the right screen shot is the exact same revision running through Visual Studio.  Notice the margins on the left side and bottom side of the window.  Any idea how/why this would happen?  I would post the XAML, but I'm not sure which part would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Does the window size also change when running in Release configuration vs. Debug configuration?  Do you have any code in `#if` regions that might account for the difference?  Have you tried using Snoop to see if any elements within the window are sized differently?

Comment: The window looks the same between Debug and Release configuration.  There is no code in #if regions.  I haven't ever used Snoop, but I'll download it and give it a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting you have something in the first part of your XAML that says says like d:DesignHeight.  This is only used when your're editing it in XAML, not during runtime.  You could just get rid of any DesignHeight / Width in your XAML and it should then look the same.  Try deleting anything like this:

```
mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="360"
```

Comment: I don't have anything like that in my XAML for this window